# Why is this undefined in a function defined and called in a JS class method. I exepected this to be window

Tags: javascript, this

I thought I understood the mechanism of this in JS but ->
 I can't explain why if you define and call a function in the method of a JS Class (syntax Class),
this value of 'this' in this function is undefined when I expected it to be window.

Not included in the snipet but I tried to check if the context of the method was executed in strict mode and it was not.

I tried the code in js fiddle and on my chrome browser console.

```js
class ComponentClass {
    classMethod() {
      function funcInMethod() {
        console.log('this in in the function funcInMethod defined and called from the method class: ', this);
      }      
      funcInMethod();
    }
 }
 
var classInstance = new ComponentClass(); 
classInstance.classMethod();

// logged: > undefined
// expected: > window
```

Comment: No constructor?

Comment: @zer00ne No. it's because `funcInMethod` context is not binded to the parent context.

Comment: But funcInMethod should create it's own scope with this set to itself, not be undefined

Comment: 'Class' is only available in ES6. Try running it with babel.

Comment: @UniqIdentifierAssignedAtBirth in strict mode, the behaviour is different

Comment: @UniqIdentifierAssignedAtBirth no it should not. It defines inner 'this' as pointer to the context of the function, and the context itself is undefined/window by default. You can call function in desired context with .call, .apply, .bind, in which case inner function's 'this' will point to context you provided

Comment: @DanilaAlpatov I dont' think you are using the word context correctly. A context refers to an isolation level at the javascript virtual machine where code executed within the context is self-contained and sandboxed. https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-0.8/df/d69/classv8_1_1_context.html What you are referring to here is some intricacy related to the binding of `this` in relation to es6 classes

Comment: @UniqIdentifierAssignedAtBirth it has nothing to do with classes specifically, that is standartized js behaviour, it will behave exactly the same inside or outhside any class.

https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)function(){} declaration defines its own 'this' reference to context. In 'strict mode' such context will be undefined by default, in non-strict mode it will be 'window'

2) Class declarations evaluated in strict mode by standart https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Strict_mode

Comment: @GuillaumeB just AVOID that in non-strict mode, as mentioned here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#Block-level_functions_in_non-strict_code

Comment: This is the correct answer - but you could rewrite "funcInMethod" to use a lambda as these are bound to the surrounding context.  e.g. 

`var funcInMethod = () => {
        console.log('this in in the function funcInMethod defined and called from the method class: ', this);
      }`

Comment: yes @Woody my code is part of an example to explain the differences with the lambdas ; )